# Need to convert words to strings to search by sql in ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app built on rails4 using PG and I have a questions controller where each questions has tags. I want the user to have a field where they can enter keywords separated by commas.

The problem is, the find_by_sql needs each word boundary to be a string separated by commas.

I have this right now just to test as it only works with one word unless I manually enter words like this `"ruby", "rails", "angular"`

```
Question.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM questions AS q INNER JOIN taggings AS t ON q.id = t.question_id INNER JOIN tags AS ta ON ta.id = t.tag_id WHERE ta.name IN ('#{current_user.first_name}');")
```

So again, the user will have a text input where they could put it `ruby, rails, angular`

and then I can search by those words.

I hope this makes sense and thanks in advance!

Comment: Combine my answer to the duplicate with a simple `split` and `strip` and you're done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How about:

```
query_tags = user_input.split(',').map { |i| "'" + i.strip + "'" }.join(', ')
# => "ruby", "rails", "angular"
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping strings in double quotes for SQL? And what about properly escaping things?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. it's single quotes.

Question.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM questions AS q INNER JOIN taggings AS t ON q.id = t.question_id INNER JOIN tags AS ta ON ta.id = t.tag_id WHERE ta.name IN ('Jared', 'ruby');")

Comment: Don't just wrap single quotes around the strings, use `connection.quote` to do it properly.

Comment: @muistooshort I have no idea what you are talking about or how to get it to work.

Comment: `"'" + i.strip + "'"` is a really bad idea, throw a single quote into one of the strings and everything goes sideways. You want to `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.quote(i.strip)` instead.